# How to add a Xml Node after a specific node in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add the ability to add an image to the file. 
I have the functionality to convert image to string and back to image, which works fine.

**XML File Data**

```
<MovieData>
    <Movie>
        <Name>Death Race</Name>
        <Type>Action</Type>
        <Type>Adventure</Type>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
        <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
        <Owner>N/A</Owner>
        <Location>N/A</Location>
        <SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
        <LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
        <LengthMin>51</LengthMin>
        <Time>10 : 44 : 23 PM</Time>
        <Date>10/13/2013</Date>
      </Movie>
      <Movie>
        <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
        <Type>Action</Type>
        <Type>Adventure</Type>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
        <Disk>Combo</Disk>
        <Owner>N/A</Owner>
        <Location>N/A</Location>
        <SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
        <LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
        <LengthMin>41</LengthMin>
        <Time>9 : 52 : 34 PM</Time>
        <Date>10/9/2013</Date>
      </Movie>
</MovieData>
```

**What I want it to look like:**

```
<MovieData>
      <Movie>
        <Name>Death Race</Name>
        <Type>Action</Type>
        <Type>Adventure</Type>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
        <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
        <Owner>N/A</Owner>
        <Location>N/A</Location>
        <SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
        <LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
        <LengthMin>51</LengthMin>
        <Image>string</Image>//Needs to be here.If it is after date that is fine too.
        <Time>10 : 44 : 23 PM</Time>
        <Date>10/13/2013</Date>
      </Movie>
      <Movie>
        <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
        <Type>Action</Type>
        <Type>Adventure</Type>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
        <Disk>Combo</Disk>
        <Owner>N/A</Owner>
        <Location>N/A</Location>
        <SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
        <LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
        <LengthMin>41</LengthMin>
        <Image>string</Image>
        <Time>9 : 52 : 34 PM</Time>
        <Date>10/9/2013</Date>
      </Movie>
</MovieData>
```

**Code**:

```
try
{
    string name = movieSaveImageNameTB.Text;
    string date = movieSaveImageDateTB.Text;
    string time = movieSaveImageTimeTB.Text;
    string hr = movieSaveImageHrTB.Text;
    string min = movieSaveImageMinTB.Text;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(movieListXML);
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MovieData");
    foreach (XmlNode movie in node.SelectNodes("Movie"))
    {
        if (movie != null)
        {
            if ((movie["Name"].InnerText == name) && (movie["Date"].InnerText == date) && (movie["Time"].InnerText == time) && 
                        (movie["LengthHr"].InnerText == hr) && (movie["LengthMin"].InnerText == min))
            {
                // This works but doesn't give the results i want.
                XmlNode n = doc.CreateNode(movie["Name"].NodeType, "Image", movie.NamespaceURI);
                movie.InsertAfter(n, movie.LastChild);
                doc.Save(movieListXML);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I updated it with the correct XML file format i am using. Sorry about that

I tried this.

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = movie.ChildNodes;
foreach (XmlNode nl in nodeList)
{
    if (nl.Name == "LengthMin")
    {
        XmlElement xNewChild = doc.CreateElement("Image");
        xNewChild.InnerText = "string";
        doc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(xNewChild, nl);
    }
}
```

It still shows the error saying that it is not a child of that node...

Comment: Try to write code by urself ... see the updated answer

Comment: As you said Code has been changed now u can accept the answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("E:\\test.xml");
        XmlNodeList xE = xDoc.SelectNodes("//MovieData/Movie/LengthMin");
        Dictionary<string, string> dicMovieData = null;
        if (xE != null)
        {
            for (int iVal = 0; iVal < xE.Count; iVal++)
            {
                if (xE[iVal] is XmlNode)
                {
                    XElement xElement = XElement.Parse("<Temp>" + xE[iVal].ParentNode.InnerXml + "</Temp>");
                    if (xElement != null)
                    {
                        dicMovieData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        foreach (XElement xMovieData in xElement.Descendants())
                        {
                            if (!dicMovieData.ContainsKey(xMovieData.Name.LocalName))
                                dicMovieData.Add(xMovieData.Name.LocalName, xMovieData.Value);
                        }
                        string sName = "Death Race";
                        string sDate = "10/13/2013";
                        string sTime = "10:44:23 PM";
                        string sLenghHR = "1";
                        string sLengthMin = "51";
                        if (dicMovieData != null && dicMovieData.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (string.Compare(dicMovieData["Name"], sName, true) == 0
                                && string.Compare(dicMovieData["Date"], sDate, true) == 0
                                && string.Compare(dicMovieData["Time"], sTime, true) == 0
                                && string.Compare(dicMovieData["LengthHr"], sLenghHR, true) == 0
                                && string.Compare(dicMovieData["LengthMin"], sLengthMin, true) == 0)
                            {
                                XmlElement xNewChild = xDoc.CreateElement("Image");
                                xNewChild.InnerText = "string";
                                XmlNode commonParent = xE[iVal].ParentNode;
                                commonParent.InsertAfter(xNewChild, xE[iVal]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xDoc.Save("D:\\test.xml");
        }
```

Old XMl

```
<MovieData>
<Movie>
    <Name>Death Race</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
    <Owner>N/A</Owner>
    <Location>N/A</Location>
    <SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
    <LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
    <LengthMin>51</LengthMin>
    <Time>10 : 44 : 23 PM</Time>
    <Date>10/13/2013</Date>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Combo</Disk>
    <Owner>N/A</Owner>
    <Location>N/A</Location>
    <SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
    <LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
    <LengthMin>41</LengthMin>
    <Time>9 : 52 : 34 PM</Time>
    <Date>10/9/2013</Date>
  </Movie>
 </MovieData>
```

New Xml

```
<MovieData>
 <Movie>
<Name>Death Race</Name>
<Type>Action</Type>
<Type>Adventure</Type>
<Rating>R</Rating>
<Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
<Owner>N/A</Owner>
<Location>N/A</Location>
<SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
<LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
<LengthMin>51</LengthMin>
<Image>string</Image>       /// Node Added
<Time>10 : 44 : 23 PM</Time>
<Date>10/13/2013</Date>
</Movie>
 <Movie>
<Name>Death Race 2</Name>
<Type>Action</Type>
<Type>Adventure</Type>
<Rating>R</Rating>
<Disk>Combo</Disk>
<Owner>N/A</Owner>
<Location>N/A</Location>
<SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
<LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
<LengthMin>41</LengthMin>
<Time>9 : 52 : 34 PM</Time>
<Date>10/9/2013</Date>
 </Movie>
 </MovieData>
```

Comment: I'm using XmlDocument to do all the searching. That method would make it so i have to change all my code and I'm more familiar with XmlDocument. Please provide a fix to the current code i have. Thanks for trying. I just want a fix for what i am using now.

Comment: you said XElement instead of that you have to say node

Comment: but try to use XDocument...it will be more easier to use

Comment: You are right i did say XElement instead of node i am sorry i will change title. I use XElements to add new objects to xml but i edit with LinQ. Sorry about that.

Comment: SEE THE ANSWER I HAVE UPDATED

Comment: It put this <Image Image="test" /> at the top of the xml nodes.

Comment: It says the reference node is not a child of this node. MovieData is the root node not Movie. Sorry i think that is the problem. Not really sure how to fix i tried this. "//MovieData//Movie" and it inserts the node after the Movie node.

Comment: Where yu getting error clean your xml firs then do this ... \

Comment: I have updated the code as per requirement ...  Check it .. and accept the answer

Comment: Just got back home. That works perfect thanks for all your help.

Comment: Actually that inserted that node for all movies instead of just a single one.

Comment: If it works instead of saying thanks Accept the answer by Tick it.... !!!!  :) .... i didnt get this Actually that inserted that node for all movies instead of just a single one

Comment: It doesn't work the way i need it to. It inserts that node to all movie nodes instead of just the one that it is supposed to be going into.

Comment: Hey which movie node you want to insert say that clearly and your xml pattern is not good ... say your view clearly how many movie nodes you have and ...where and all you want to insert the node

Comment: If you look in the above i search through the xml file until these fields match.     if ((movie["Name"].InnerText == name) && (movie["Date"].InnerText == date) && (movie["Time"].InnerText == time) && 
                        (movie["LengthHr"].InnerText == hr) && (movie["LengthMin"].InnerText == min))

Comment: Try to Write Code by urself Last time i am writing code for you See the updated answer

Comment: Thanks that works. Also i did try. That is why i asked the question here.